# org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled set to 'future seems to work for TODOs that have only a date and not a time

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use `org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled` set to 'future to ignore / not show TODOs in the global todo list that are scheduled in the future.

`org-agenda-todo-ignore-scheduled` set to 'future seems to work for TODOs that have only a date and not a time.

E.g. if today is Oct 23 2020 at 10 am and a TODO has a timestamp of e.g.:

```
SCHEDULED: <2020-10-24 Sat .+1d>
```

then it is not shown.

BUT a TODO with:

```
SCHEDULED: <2020-10-23 12:00 Fri .+2h>
```

is shown in the Global todo list even though it is scheduled for 2 hours into the future.

I have been searching for a variable or setting that could make the global todo list also ignore TODOs that are x hours into the future but have not been able to find anything.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I guess `future` means tomorrow or later. You can set it to 0 if you want to ignore today I think, but you won't get earlier ones for today that way. I guess the granularity unit is one day.

Comment: Thank you NickD for your input :) It makes sense that the granularity is 1 day not less. I suppose time was added to date stamps so that TODOs could be shown in a time range in the agenda...

Comment: Time is important for appointment-like TODO's, perhaps not so important for SCHEDULED-like or DEADLINE-like TODO's - at least, that's how I interpret things.

Comment: For me it is useful to repeat certain tasks that I need to do eg every 2 hours, such as take a break from work, stretch, etc. I could also see it helpful for people that would like a TODO to take eg some medicine every 6 hours, etc. I have found a solution and posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do `C-h v org-agenda-todo-ignore-time-comparison-use-seconds` and click `customize`.
- Click Value menu.
- Set it to `Compare time with seconds`.
- Save
- Restart emacs

This changes the comparison from the default value which is days.

Comment: TIL about `org-agenda-todo-ignore-time-comparison-use-seconds` - thanks!

Comment: @NickD - Thanks for sprucing up my post and all the help you have given me in many other questions :)

Comment: A good question and a good answer deserve some touch-ups to present their best face to the world :-) Thanks for the question *and* the answer!